# Sql Server 2008 ' If ' Condition to check whether a column exists in a table not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I had  a  column called  SkypeID in a table  and  I dropped it. The  query  I have used is  as follows,

```
IF NOT  EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.columns
        WHERE Name = N'SkypeID' AND Object_ID = Object_ID(N'Mstr_OnlineDetails'))
BEGIN
Alter Table  Mstr_OnlineDetails
 Drop column  SkypeID
END
```

The  query executed successfully .
And If I  write  the  following query and  check  ,  the 'IF'  condition  fails.

```
IF   EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.columns
        WHERE Name = N'SkypeID' AND Object_ID = Object_ID(N'Mstr_OnlineDetails'))
BEGIN
 Update  Mstr_OnlineDetails  Set  OnlineQuery  = SkypeID
END
```

The  query result says  Invalid column SkypeID .
I cross  checked  by  Executing the  following  query ,

```
SELECT * FROM sys.columns
        WHERE Name = N'SkypeID' AND Object_ID = Object_ID(N'Mstr_OnlineDetails')
```

It returned  an  empty  result .  Then how the If Condition fails?
Any help would  be  appreciated

Comment: can u plz check your first query (IF NOT EXISTS THEN DROP ...)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this error during the compilation phase of the script.  The `THEN` is being parsed . . . and your error is a parse error.

One method is to switch to dynamic SQL:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.columns WHERE Name = N'SkypeID' AND Object_ID = Object_ID(N'Mstr_OnlineDetails'))
BEGIN
     exec sp_executesql N'Update  Mstr_OnlineDetails Set OnlineQuery  = SkypeID'
END;
```